# How do you keep your database synchronized in team?

Tags: mysql

there are three developers, a test server and the product. The database must be consistents all the time, but I cant imagine how to do it properly:

```
developer1: CREATE TABLE A, ALTER TABLE A
developer2: ALTER TABLE B
developer3: ALTER TABLE C
```

in addition, project master dont want to put tables on the product which are irrevelant right now, e.g. `C` table

Comment: If you have a single test server and all developers make changes on that server, then the database will always be consistent, since they see the same set of tables and data. When you migrate changes to production, then you know exactly what data structure changes are to be migrated. So, I do not really understand the question.

Comment: but if table A has x,y,z columns, we all 3 changes that, how will he update it to the production? Will he create the ALTER commands by hand? Remember, ts a production, the SHOW CREATE TABLE and TRUNCATE wont work

Comment: if all 3 of you change a single table, then you have to create a migration package based on the difference between the production table and the last version of the table in test. There are tools out there that can compare source and target schemas and generate the DML statements required to sync them.